# How best to restrict types in Generic <T> class, where all are derived from same base class

Tags: c#, generics, dynamics-crm

I work with Dynamics CRM (Which is technically irrelevant to this discussion, but explains some of the back-story to this issue).  There are numerous types all derived from the class `Entity`.  I wish to create a `Class<T>() : where T: Entity`, but with a further restriction, that it only operates on specific classes derived from `Entity`.

My current method of doing this is to have an `enum` matching the entity names I want to use, `if/else if/else` my way through those types, and `throw` if an invalid type is passed in.

It feels clumsy, and I feel that I would be better off writing something like,

`public class ProductConverter<t> where T: Entity (OpportunityProduct, QuoteProduct, AccountProduct)
{ ... }`

That way the type-engine can say, "We're working on a base class of Entity, and also we're only working on these derived types of Entity".

I hope this gives enough clarity to understand what I'm doing - my purpose is that I want to create an engine that will handle conversion between Entity Records, that can be extended without having to re-write large chunks of code (Effectively, adding a mapping and type parameters).  I'm sure there are better ways to do this, so please point them out if you see them :)

`edit`
@henk-holterman asked if I could change the classes.  This isn't possible as they're generated class files, used as an interface to the Dynamics CRM web service.

`edit`
As noted by @jamiec, the classes are `partial`, so I can do this by defining an interface on the specific classes I wish to modify.

Comment: Can you change the entity classes?  Add an interface? Why isn't there a `Product` base class?

Comment: No, they're auto-generated as interfaces to the system, I have limited control over that.  I'll update the question.

Comment: just use `typeof` to test the class type then you can use a switch statement and abstract out for each type.

Comment: @bilpor That's basically what I'm doing at present, I was wondering if there was a better (More generic) way of doing this...

Comment: @PeterStreet The more generic way is to implement a Interface which must be implemented from every member you want to use in your method. You can do where T : Entity, IProduct for example.

Comment: Makes sense, @Sebi, and I'd love to be able to do that; unfortunately as they're generated classes, every time I refresh the metadata, the classes will regenerate and I'll end up losing the interface.  I have thought about creating specific holder classes that inherit from Entity and have a dummy interface I can use, and casting into that... not sure about the performance impact though.

Comment: Most autogenerated classes generate `partial` classes for this exact reason - so you can add your own code which isnt blown away by a regen. In your case you would just have `public partial class QuoteProduct : IProduct {}` in a separate file to the autogenerated one.

Comment: @jamiec Bingo - thanks, I'd not noticed that.  Thanks very much, I can do it via interfacing with some tweaks.  Fantastic.  Between all of you, you've gotten to the answer - not sure who should post an answer on this one to get the credit?

Comment: @PeterStreet you could edit the question to reflect the fact that **your specific** generated classes are `partial` (if they are) and then Jamiec can write an answer that belongs to the question if he wants ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your autogenerated classes are almost certainly `partial`, which means that you should have a separate file for each implementing a shared interface

```
 public partial class QuoteProduct : IProduct 
 { // probably empty }
```

Then you can restrict your generic type by interface:

```
public class ProductConverter<T> where T: Entity, IProduct 
{ // your implementation }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - as you mentioned, they are `partial`, so that converter will work perfectly with an interface.  That interface will also allow me to genericise some of the other conversion requirements that I was wondering how best to do, so it all works out well.

Comment: @PeterStreet cool, glad I could help with a flippant/throwaway comment. Sometimes you miss the wood for the trees ;)

Comment: [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) with Stack Overflow for the duck ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an Interface which is then implemented from every class you want to use. This could look like this for example:

```
public interface IProduct
{
   int ProductId {get;set;}
}

public class ProductConverter<t> where T: Entity, IProduct
{
   //Do sth. with your ProductId
}
```

Because your classes are generated as you described in comment this won't work in your special case. Then you only have the ability to use type checking:

```
T obj;
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(YourClass))

//OR

if (obj is YourClass)
```

The problem is if you do sth. like you expect in your question, your variable is useless because you don't know which type it is.

```
 public void ProductConverter<t>(T obj) where T: Entity (OpportunityProduct, QuoteProduct)
 {
    obj. //What to do here?? It can hold Methods from both OpportunityProduct or QuoteProduct
 }
```

So in fact you have the possibilty to generalize the stuff you need or to typecheck.

If you know what can happen maybe the [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword can help you. In this case you don't need the generic approach. For example this can look like this:

```
public void ProductConverter(dynamic entity)
{
   //Make sure the method exists. Or you will get an Exception.
   //The compiler can't warn you about this
   entity.SomeMethod1();
   entity.SomeMethod2();
}
```

Not sure if this can really help you if you want to write a converter.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I did fail to notice that the generated classes were `partial`, which will enable me to append my own classes onto this...  Silly of me not to notice, but I was a bit code-blind to what was generated.  This way, I can implement the conversion methods directly onto each class to generate the other classes, without worrying about collisions.

Comment: @PeterStreet Well, happy to hear that you found a solution.